# Flutter Provider: MaterialApp.router depends on provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm trying to make my MaterialApp.router reactive using the state from the provider.

But I'm running into some issue, mainly the hot reload in debug mode is not working.

I checked online that you should not put variable inside the MaterialApp.router build method, but how do you make it reactive to the state without putting it inside the build method?

My root provider:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MultiProvider(
     providers: [
       StreamProvider<User?>.value(
         value: AuthService().user,
         initialData: AuthService().currentUser,
       ),
     ],
     child: App(),
   );
 }
```

My App:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final user = Provider.of<User?>(context); 

   return MaterialApp.router(
     routerDelegate: AutoRouterDelegate.declarative(
       _appRouter,
       routes: (_) => [
         if (user != null) const HomeRoute() else const LoginRoute(),
       ],
     ),
     routeInformationParser: _appRouter.defaultRouteParser(
       includePrefixMatches: true,
     ),
     // darkTheme: DefaultTheme.dark(),
   );
 }
```

Edit: by not working, I mean the emulator just went white screen and need to restart the app

Answer (score 0):

Don't use final user = Provider.of(context), use Consumer instead.
You need to use a better implementation of navigator 2.0, i recommend to follow this guide https://medium.com/geekculture/a-simpler-guide-to-flutter-navigator-2-0-part-i-70623cedc93b or to switch for Navigator 1 which is more easy to use with MaterialApp(routes: [list of routes], initialRoute: etc).